# Can I set default values with matplotlib and pandas for each x tick?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```py
# Ratings by day, divided by Staff member

from datetime import datetime as dt

by_staff = df.groupby('User ID')

plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))

# Those are used to calculate xticks and yticks
xmin, xmax = pd.to_datetime(dt.now()), pd.to_datetime(0)
ymin, ymax = 0, 0

for index, data in by_staff:

    by_day = data.groupby('Date')
    
    x = pd.to_datetime(by_day.count().index)
    y = by_day.count()['Value']
    
    xmin = min(xmin, x.min())
    xmax = max(xmax, x.max())
    
    ymin = min(ymin, min(y))
    ymax = max(ymax, max(y))

    plt.plot_date(x, y, marker='o', label=index, markersize=12)

plt.title('Ratings by day, by Staff member', fontdict = {'fontsize': 25})
plt.xlabel('Day', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('n° of ratings for that day', fontsize=15)

ticks = pd.date_range(xmin, xmax, freq='D')

plt.xticks(ticks, rotation=60)
plt.yticks(range(ymin, ymax + 1))

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.grid()

plt.legend([a for a, b in by_staff],
          title="Ratings given",
          loc="center left",
          bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0, 0.5, 1))

plt.show()
```

I'd like to set the value shown at a specific xtick to 0 if there's no data for the day. Currently, this is the plot shown:

[image: The plot shown]

I tried some Google searches, but I can't seem to explain my problem correctly. How could I solve this?

My dataset: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/311932890017693700/800789506328100934/sample-ratings.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to simplify the task by letting pandas aggregate the data. We group by Date and User ID simultaneously and then [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) the dataframe. This allows us to fill the missing data points with a preset value like 0.The form `x = df.groupby(["Date",'User ID']).count().Value.unstack(fill_value=0)` is compact chaining for `a= df.groupby(["Date",'User ID'])`, `b=a.count()`, `c=b.Value`, `x=c.unstack(fill_value=0)`. You can print out each intermediate result of these chained pandas operations to see what it does.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep=",", parse_dates=["Date"])

#by_staff = df.groupby(["Date",'User ID']) - group entries by date and ID
#.count - count identical date-ID pairs
#.Value - use only this column
#.unstack(fill_value=0) bring resulting data from long to wide form
#and fill missing data with zero
by_staff = df.groupby(["Date",'User ID']).count().Value.unstack(fill_value=0)

ax = by_staff.plot(marker='o', markersize=12, linestyle="None", figsize=(15,8))

plt.title('Ratings by day, by Staff member', fontdict = {'fontsize': 25})
plt.xlabel('Day', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('n° of ratings for that day', fontsize=15)

#labeling only the actual rating values shown in the grid
plt.yticks(range(df.Value.max() + 1))
#this is not really necessary, it just labels zero differently
#labels = ["No rating"] + [str(i) for i in range(1, df.Value.max() + 1)]
#ax.set_yticklabels(labels)

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.grid()

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

Obviously, you don't see multiple entries.

Comment: Could you add some comments to your code so it's easier to understand the working process?

Comment: The point is to group by both date and ID directly instead of two points. The form `x = df.groupby(["Date",'User ID']).count().Value.unstack(fill_value=0)` is compact chaining for `a= df.groupby(["Date",'User ID'])`, `b=a.count()`, `c=b.Value`, `x=c.unstack(fill_value=0)`. You can print out each intermediate result of these chained pandas operations to see what it does.